# Comma Separated Numbers Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a comma separated list for numbers 1-8.

i.e. `2,4,6,8,1` is valid input.

I tried `[0-8,]*` but it seems to accept `1234` as valid. It is not requiring a comma and it is letting me type in a number larger than 8. I am not sure why.

Comment: The comma needs to be outside the character class, and grouped to the numeric character using parentheses. That is: `([0-8],)+`

Comment: You say you want the number 1-8, but your regex is trying to match 0-8. Which is it?

Comment: 1-8 only nothing high than 8

Comment: Just for the answer to your question be somewhat explicit here; if it accepts 1234 as valid it will accept abcd as well, as there are 0 matches which is what you asked for with *

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`[0-8,]*` will match zero or more consecutive instances of `0` through `8` or `,`, anywhere in your string. You want something more like this:

```
^[1-8](,[1-8])*$
```

`^` matches the start of the string, and `$` matches the end, ensuring that you're examining the entire string. It will match a single digit, plus zero or more instances of a comma followed by a digit after it.

Comment: it will break if I will try to check against the values 1234, 1345 , 4455

Comment: In a more general case, [`^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xbxBV7/1) (since the title - *Comma Separated Numbers Regex* - sounds broader than what OP describes in the question body).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in an even more general case, you could use `^\d+(,\d+)*$` because `\d` means "digit", or `[0-9]` in base 10

Comment: @chharvey `\d` is not supported by some regex engines, like POSIX, so `[0-9]` is safer in the context of a question that has only one, `regex`, tag. This is why I did not use a non-capturing group in my answer.

Answer (score 35):

```
/^\d+(,\d+)*$/
```

- for at least one digit, otherwise you will accept 1,,,,,4

Comment: OP is trying to validate a comma-separated list of digits from 0 through 8 inclusive, not a comma-separated list of any number of digits.

Comment: But it actually answers the 'headline' question which is why I'm here

Comment: Variation on a theme: To accept optional white space around each number (including before the first number, and after the last number), eg `1,22, 3 , 4444 ,  5`, then regex is `^\s*\d+\s*(,\s*\d+\s*)*$` .  Useful if your users have a tendency to add spaces after the commas.

Answer (score 10):

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)+
```

This works better for me for comma separated numbers in general, like: 1,234,933

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this Regex:

```
^[1-8](,[1-8])+$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python and looking to find out all possible matching strings like 
XX,XX,XXX or X,XX,XXX
or 12,000, 1,20,000 using regex

```
string = "I spent 1,20,000 on new project "
re.findall(r'(\b[1-8]*(,[0-9]*[0-9])+\b)', string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

> ```
> Result will be --->  [('1,20,000', ',000')]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need a number + comma combination that can repeat:

```
 ^[1-8](,[1-8])*$
```

If you don't want remembering parentheses add `?:` to the parens, like so:

```
 ^[1-8](?:,[1-8])*$
```

Comment: 21,22,24,343546 is valid with this expression. The highest number can only be 8