# How can I use regular expression for multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to generate a regex which would match the following sequence-

- +911111111111,+912222222222,+913333333333,+914444444444

It should not allow any other character other than + and numbers

I have tried this->

```
/^(\+91)\d{10}$/
```

But it works only for one phone number not for multiple phone numbers

Comment: [tag:javascript] or [tag:php]?

Comment: http://regex101.com

Comment: [**`/^\+91\d{10}(?:,\+91\d{10})*$/`**](https://regex101.com/r/lE0gH0/2)

Comment: In any language..I jst want regular expression that would check multiple values not single

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That will not check for repeating patterns

Comment: @Tushar: There is no repeated patterns I believe. That is just a poor sample input, I think.

Comment: There is considerable variation is the capability (and accepted syntax) of different regex engines. It is quite possible there is no "universal" regex.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620980/comma-separated-numbers-regex

Comment: With regex it is important to have very clear and specific requirements. Other than trivial cases a small change in requirements will have a big impact on the regex needed. Please update question with 1. a statement of what is needed; 2. multiple examples that should match; and 3. examples of what should almost but not quite match.

Comment: do you need [
  "+911111111111",
  "+912222222222",
  "+913333333333",
  "+914444444444"
] above kinda result

Comment: No..I was needed the regular expression that could validate the above sequence

Answer (score 1):

If

```
^\+\d{11}$
```

(a `+` followed by 11 digits) is not sufficient you'll need to be more specific about what you want to allow and not-allow.

*Update following comment*: the first two digits are "91" so those can be specified, and then ten further digits:

```
^\+91\d{10}$
```

Comment: Every phone number should starts with +91 and followed by 10 digits.And multiple values should get checked

Comment: @Tushar That requirement is not clear in the question... (but is now)

Comment: @Tushar Operative word "guess" (and the whole multiple values requirement seems to be bouncing around). Question is increasingly unclear.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I interpreted question wrong and edited it to make it different. OP's requirements is [comma-separated phone numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163979/how-can-i-use-regular-expression-for-multiple-values#comment65670787_39164022), please update the answer.