# matching comma separated values in MySQL on join

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a few tables i need to join, i cannot change the database as it's being used in multiple different applications.

The first table looks like the following

```
id, list_of_foreign_id


1, "1, 3, 4, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 23"

2, "1, 3, 4, 8, 23"

3, "1, 3, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 23"

4, "7"

....
```

And the forrening table is simply joined on ID and could look like the following

```
ID, name

1, "john Oliver"

2, "John Doe"

3, "Arthur Dent"

....
```

And i need to match the list of ids in table to to the id on table two.

The query is going to look like the following but i'm unsure about the join condition

```
Select ...
from
A
join
B on a.list_of_foreign_id contains B.id
```

I'm thinking it can be done using regex.

I've tried with locate, but it also matches sub-strings like 1, 3 will match to 13. etc.

I've also looked around and found this post, 
[Comma Separated Numbers Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620980/comma-separated-numbers-regex)
But I'm unsure how to look with regex for specific cases.

Comment: Commalists are usually a 'bad schema design'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
SELECT *
       FROM A
            INNER JOIN B
                       ON find_in_set(B.id, A.list_of_foreign_id);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in practice as it only returns the first match.

Comment: And? One match is enough to decide that "`a.list_of_foreign_id contains B.id`" as you requested.