# Comma separated value in Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex that will match the following comma separated value:

```
Pattern: A,A,A
Where A contains only digits or digits separated by "|" 
e.g. A = 111 or A = 111|222
```

The valid string could be

```
111,222|333,444
or
111|222,333,444
```

And the regex I have

```
^[[,]?[[\d]*|[\d]*\|[\d]*]]*$
```

However, when I test it, it returned true for the following patterns

```
111,222|333,
111,222,333|
,111,222,333|444
|111,222|333,444
```

How could I modify my regex to return false for those strings starting with "|" or "," and ended with "|" or ","

Comment: Is there only one `|` or can there be multiple `111|222|333,444`?

Comment: in my case, there is only 1 "|"
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620980/comma-separated-numbers-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern with an optional group to match the `|` and 1 or more digits:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)?,)+\d+(?:\|\d+)?$
```

That would match

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:\|\d+)?,` Optionally match `|` and 1+ digits followed by a `,`
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times (or `*` to repeat 0+ times)
- `\d+(?:\|\d+)?` match 1+ digits and optionally match `|` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ndiv5/1)

Note that you can omit the brackets around `\d` and the comma.

---

If there can be multiple `|`, you can use the pattern suggested by [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels):

```
 ^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)*,)+\d+(?:\|\d+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pOu20S/1)

Comment: I think `^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)*,)+\d+(?:\|\d+)*$` if multiple `|` are possible?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes that is possible :) I saw only one `|` in the examples though, but you can post it of course.

Comment: You can just add it to yours if you want, keep it clean.

Comment: `^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)?,)+\d+(?:\|\d+)?$` is more efficient btw (switched the order - quantified first).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.
What if I want to include both 111 and 111|222 ?
I tried this ^\d+(?:\|\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\|\d+)?)*$ and it seems to work.

Comment: @user3422290 Then you could use `*` as a quantifier instead of `+` like `^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)?,)*\d+(?:\|\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/6uRz31/1

Comment: This is what I need
^(?:\d+(?:\|\d+)?,)*\d+(?:\|\d+)?$
Thank you