# regex to allow only single digit or two digit numbers and comma in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I searched internet and even followed the documentation of RegEx but unable to solve the issue.
I want to validate single digit or double digit number.
It should only accept

Use Case1: string sDate= ",01,23,05,1,28,25";

Use Case1: string sDate= ",01,23,05,1,28,25,";

Use Case1: string sDate= "01,23,05,1,28,25,";

Use Case1: string sDate= "01,23,05,1,28,25";

It should not accept anything i.e. no decimal, characters, special character except comma.
I have written a code in C#

string stDate= ",01,23,05,1,28,25";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sDate))

```
            {
                Regex r = new Regex(@"^(\d+[,]\d*|\d*[,]\d+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
                if (r.IsMatch(sDate))
                {
business logic
}
}
else
{
//business logic
}
```

I need to know where I"m going wrong. When I'm entering a alphabet in the string it is accepting it even.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
enter code here
enter code here

Comment: If you validate the whole input, use `^,?\d+(?:,\d+)*,?$`

Comment: For just validation - alteration of @WiktorStribiżew's - `^,?\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2})*,?$`
To also get the matches - `^,?(\d{1,2})(?:,(\d{1,2}))*,?$`
Test them here: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 1):

To match optional repetitions of 1 or 2 digits where the comma can be at the start, end or in between, you can use:

```
^,?\d\d?(?:,\d\d?)*,?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `,?\d\d?` Match optional comma, a digit and optional digit
- `(?:,\d\d?)*` Match 0 or more repetitions of a comma, digit and optional digit
- `,?` Match optional comma
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IR6rtR/1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `new Regex(@"^(,\d{1,2})+$")` would work for you.

Your regex of `^(\d+[,]\d*|\d*[,]\d+)$` starts out by expecting one or more digits through `\d+` followed by a mandatory comma, followed by any number of digits through `\d*` OR any number of digits again.

Sites like [this](https://regex101.com/) are great for testing and practicing regexes. The site actually tests php but there is no significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
Regex r = new Regex(@"\A,?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*,?\z", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA%2C%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5B0-9%5D%2B%29*%2C%3F%5Cz&i=%2C01%2C23%2C05%2C1%2C28%2C25).

**Relevant posts**:

- [\d less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9)
- [How do I match an entire string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123455/how-do-i-match-an-entire-string-with-a-regex)
- [Comma Separated Numbers Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620980/comma-separated-numbers-regex/16621003)

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```